# Can I purchase and download Halo 2 for windows online somewhere?

Tags: halo-2

I have Googled this to no avail. Every place I've found that sells this game insists on shipping it.

1. I don't want to wait
2. I don't want to pay for shipping on a digital product that can just as well be downloaded
3. I'm stubborn

So if there's somewhere I can purchase and **download** Halo 2, I offer you reputation points for the location. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no place where you can purchase and download a **digital legit copy**, at the moment.

Usually Microsoft PC Games can be bought [here](http://www.gamesforwindows.com/) but, for some reasons, Halo 2 is not available ATM.

Answer (score -5):

Best Option if you download the game it self from torrent and after when the game asking for the key just call microsoft and buy the key for $16 and you dont have to wait and pay for shipping :-)